# Tiles Decoration Filter example

Tags: jakarta-ee, decorator, servlet-filters, tiles

I'm trying to use [Decoration Filter](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/apidocs/org/apache/tiles/web/util/TilesDecorationFilter.html) in Tiles, but cannot clearly understand how does it work.

> The filter will intercept all requests to the indicated url pattern store the initial request path as the "body" attribute and then render the "test.definition" definition. The filter will only redecorate those requests which do not contain the request attribute associated with the prevent token "layout".

I just don't get it... Is it supposed to be the same as Decorator pattern? Or can anyone provide a different example with a simple explanation?

edit: I found also [this material](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3697171/Tip-Use-Tiles-Decorations-Reduce-Configuration.htm). THe author says:

> The filter configuration below will intercept all JSP requests that are forwarded to, configure the tiles definition called "standard" with an attribute called "body," and invoke that definition.

Still I don't understand :/ Does it mean that I have just a forward action (e.g. I submit a form, it is processed and then I'm forwarded to the homepage) and the filter creates a specific definition that is rendered somewhere? But where is this definition defined? Or where is this definition rendered?